# How can I dynamically re-map an object full of functions using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm kinda new to TypeScript, and I've run into a bit of a wall with something.

I have a plain object of functions, which operate on some state, like so:

```
const queries = {
  getRoom(state: State, roomID: string) {
    return state.rooms[roomID]
  },
  isPlayerInRoom(state: State, roomID: string) {
    return state.player.roomID === roomID
  }
}
```

I'd like to transform this object so that each function can be called without the first argument.

In regular JS, I'd probably just do something like:

```
function wrap(object, store) {
  const newObject = {}
  for (const name in object) {
    const func = object[name]
    newObject[name] = (...args) => func(store.getState(), ...args)
  }
  return newObject
}

const newQueries = wrap(queries, store)
newQueries.getRoom(5)
```

However with TypeScript, the types are not retained.

How can I ensure that my wrap function has the correct return type?

I'm sure I could take a different approach here, however I'd rather learn how to do exactly this, as it may come in handy in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the compiler is anywhere near clever enough to follow the flow of that function and infer the types you want them to be.  According to the TypeScript standard library, `Object.entries(obj)` [returns an array](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L38) of `[string, T]` tuples where `T` is the union of all property types of `obj`.  In order to even begin to hope for the compiler to do it for you automatically, you'd need `Object.entries(obj)` to return an array of correlated key-value types of type `[K0, V0] | [K1, V1] | ...` which you could write, but it's probably not worth it to try to [augment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) the typings for `Object.entries()` for just a single use case.

Instead what you can do is represent the desired type manipulation yourself, which will be a combination of [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types.  Then, make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function whose call signature returns this type, and whose implementation uses as many [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) as you need to make the compiler happy with the typings it can't verify... or equivalently, do a single [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) with the desired signature, and an implementation signature lax enough so the compiler doesn't complain.  Like this:

```
// pull the first argument off a function
type StripFirstArgument<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
  F extends (first: any, ...rest: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => R : never;

// take an argument of type A, and an object of type T
// where T's properties are all functions whose first argument is type A
// and return a new object of partially applied functions  
function partiallyApplyObject<A, T extends {
  [K in keyof T]: (a: A, ...rest: any[]) => any
}>(
  a: A,
  t: T
): { [K in keyof T]: StripFirstArgument<T[K]> };

// lax implementation signature
function partiallyApplyObject(a: any, t: { [k: string]: Function }) {
  const ret: { [k: string]: Function } = {};
  for (let [k, f] of Object.entries(t)) {
    ret[k] = (...args: any[]) => t[k](a, ...args);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

And let's see if it works:

```
const newQueries = partiallyApplyObject(store.getState(), queries);
newQueries.getRoom(5); // error, 5 isn't a string
newQueries.isPlayerInRoom("five"); // boolean
```

Looks good to me.  Maybe this is more complicated that you'd like, but hopefully it makes sense, and at any rate you can appreciate the scope of the task you were hoping the compiler would do automatically.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes all makes sense, although I'll definitely need to read up on mapped and conditional types to get my head around the syntax. It's more complex than I had hoped, but no more complex than I expected ;) Thanks!