# Typescript: Map object props types in wrapped function to omit certain props

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to wrap an `actions` object with functions as properties. Each function has an ActionContext argument.

When defining the functions the `state` property in the context should be accessible. But when calling the method `state` should not be accessible anymore, as it will be injected.

I first tried to do this with 2 separate args in each function, but that felt wrong and seemed not flexible enough. Therefor I'm using just 1 `ctx` argument now.

**Solution approach #1:** [How can I dynamically re-map an object full of functions using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53798215/how-can-i-dynamically-re-map-an-object-full-of-functions-using-typescript)

The return type on `useActions = (state: any): T` is ofcourse not correct, but here I want the types in the `actions`-object to be mapped from type Action to type CallableAction with their inferred `Context`-type.

But I'm struggling how to infer these types, if at all possible. Or maybe I'm just Typing too much? Quite new to typescript.

```js
type ActionContext<S=any, P=any> = { state: S, params: P };
type Action = <T extends ActionContext>(ctx: T) => any;
type CallableActionContext<T> = T extends ActionContext ? Omit<T, 'state'> : never
type CallableAction<T=any> = (ctx: CallableActionContext<T>) => any
type SaveActionContext = ActionContext<any, {id: string}>

interface Supplier {
  name: string;
}
// add ctx types in actions
const actions = {
  save: async (ctx: SaveActionContext): Promise<Supplier> => {
    console.log('Mocked: useActions.save');
    const tralala = ctx.params.id
    await Promise.resolve(tralala)
    return {name: 's1'};
  }
}

// this is what the resulting action object should look like
// calling mapped actions and omitting `state` property):
// const save: CallableAction<SaveActionContext> = (ctx) => {
//   ctx.params.id
//   return new SupplierVM
// }
// const ret = save({params:{id: '2'}})

const createActions = <T extends Record<keyof T, Action>>(actions: T) => {
  const useActions = (state: any): T => {
    const injectCtx = (action: Action, ctx: any) => {
      const enrichedCtx = {...ctx, state: state} as ActionContext
      return action(enrichedCtx)
    }

    return Object.entries(actions).reduce((prev: any, [fnName, fn]: any) => ({
      ...prev,
      [fnName]: (ctx: any) => injectCtx(fn, ctx)
    }), {});
  }

  return useActions
}

const state = reactive({})
const useActions = createActions(actions)
const acts = useActions(state)
acts.save({params: { id: '3'}, state: {}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should change `(state: any): T`:

```
const useActions = (state: any): { [K in keyof T]: CallableAction<Parameters<T[K]>[0]> } => {
```

We're going through each action, getting the first parameter, (SaveActionContext), then we pass that to `CallableAction` which gives us our desired context type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQWAUALgngDgpsAggYwgSwPYDsDC2JwAeEAPAMoC8AhllADTAAK1tAfMBcAN7ADOEVAgC5gZBjCoAnKgFteIxsAC+AbnDR4SVJiwdgJACrAiBLABNeW9NjxYCxVgApUhEQYCUHdjShrIsBBwqABtgqgAjYLgUa1x8E0N2TiMTOHNLGJ1bewhgAH5gAHkZNFIDBgByfkE4CvYRLDgANzhJdQDgINCIqMzsQxYoJOBnCFdOkLDI6O0beOJEzwpvWnbNMioWvri7Ez1t7ISfBi40MxF+STQsAHMlVnBwa4JJADMqZAQyAFcYGGC0K1uOBgMAsLI4BcIFdbn4lOAAPQI4BUMxmYAuYAaOCWa4o2ZYXjgZDYfj42KWThcEF8TaQlG8KBYZAjFwiDZbAmHYjuBSSDAlXhwci-f6AyRJdjUsCg0EkwkYKIAOmCGBujgqAFkMMgANZwc7Ab5C7a8JW8OkVdx+WUY0m5aEhJ16FxKiTSORKs400FUADuVFKTH5grgSskOMVLUcjrCYXcPuAEYg30kui44Jk9KqAEYKqoafCwEXEciIAALNC4yx+8uCLHlhAR3jfYLoW7knTADDhABWcFQfHLGFb6NVGF1wAB+tLGMm1xuwBkVD+Bs7pJR5m7JQg7cXAANqgR98AYPz4JJoLzZ-KyRaWiIulNegTyHSDvMIMNRoQllLZ3KYxulIshmt6YBIrKyaprojR+qIooAq0ABqmqzkWkG3rkyZ6PecCOFw7qgUIpyGhUABM+ZKAmYDEvaGIRjUpp6IYxjEGkFjAAASgOGCSGYJD6lAGCvMA5RWDorBOB8FJuH+wIynahK5MaMwUnojhHvSPi8twwAANoANLAHiQkiWJAC6j6TD0ak6CQjAgVmLy8IYRkWaw+kAAwecoXgKbaWEmVg-aoDgYwaTJOgiNsDBspuUDydKtpyvRaRXMgjZmOFhB6FwSoFS4DBaVCNRKAyElzLsxCJqC0FpuuWCOOlaCZQaOU0baJaKXVcApg1hR9gOEBKmk0KArwjhRaS7jhga3yfI4jhns0IjHAZrxYAAchCDCbVZCXyQRtXAAVboRk0dAnfpm07VmB1LfFOn+dcoUQDljibXFYzuJ1srUSc1GFo8in1boqmmuA3VBVpeVFkFEMEpSDFwExSNTUjNFBTJyOIxSmkCAQNE4+adIEURcgiDwZwiBUADMVHuEAA)

Comment: Ah wow, seems so obvious when I read this ^^, thank you! Although I think the whole logic can be even more simplified, but we'll see!

When testing though the return type was lost, so I added a second type param `,ReturnType<T[K]>` to `CallableAction<T,R>` and used that as a return type for the function.